# Error with file "/platforms/android/app/build.gradle" in new project (line 505)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I started yesterday a course on NativeScript and just finished installing everything (nativescript, typescript, android studio, android sdk, android emulator).

I created an empty project and run
`tns build android --bundle` (also tried without the `--bundle` flag but it didn't work either)

I have an error at 50% of the building, and after researching for hours, I was not able to find a solution.

This is the output:

```
Copying template files...
Platform android successfully added. v5.3.1
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Running webpack for android...
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/user/Desktop/coding/project-name/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/**/* has been removed.
Hash: 3e08d144c4208c0b1de0
Version: webpack 4.23.1
Time: 13040ms
Built at: 04/08/2019 9:18:05 PM
                                                 Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
             App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml   1.36 KiB          [emitted]  
                      App_Resources/Android/app.gradle  486 bytes          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/drawable-hdpi/background.png   3.42 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png    6.8 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-hdpi/logo.png   32.4 KiB          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/drawable-ldpi/background.png   1.31 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png   3.23 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-ldpi/logo.png   9.95 KiB          [emitted]  
    App_Resources/Android/drawable-mdpi/background.png   1.89 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   3.42 KiB          [emitted]  
          App_Resources/Android/drawable-mdpi/logo.png   15.8 KiB          [emitted]  
App_Resources/Android/drawable-nodpi/splash_screen.xml  304 bytes          [emitted]  
   App_Resources/Android/drawable-xhdpi/background.png   5.26 KiB          [emitted]  
         App_Resources/Android/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png   10.4 KiB          [emitted]  
         App_Resources/Android/drawable-xhdpi/logo.png     54 KiB          [emitted]  
  App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxhdpi/background.png   10.3 KiB          [emitted]  
        App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png   20.3 KiB          [emitted]  
        App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxhdpi/logo.png    116 KiB          [emitted]  
 App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.png   3.87 KiB          [emitted]  
       App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png   73.8 KiB          [emitted]         App_Resources/Android/drawable-xxxhdpi/logo.png    193 KiB          [emitted]  
           App_Resources/Android/values-v21/colors.xml  104 bytes          [emitted]  
           App_Resources/Android/values-v21/styles.xml  902 bytes          [emitted]  
               App_Resources/Android/values/colors.xml  237 bytes          [emitted]  
               App_Resources/Android/values/styles.xml   1.68 KiB          [emitted]  
                                             bundle.js   18.9 KiB  bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                          package.json  134 bytes          [emitted]  
                                            starter.js   39 bytes          [emitted]  
                                   tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes          [emitted]  
                                             vendor.js   4.99 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 452 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 1.06 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.css] 19 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 64 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 982 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 1.67 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.routes.ts] 236 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.css] 19 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.html] 273 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.ts] 1.28 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 1.95 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 121 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 404 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete.
Project successfully prepared (android)
Building project...
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from /home/user/Desktop/coding/project-name/App_Resources/Android/app.
gradle
         + using support library version 28.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /home/user/Desktop/coding/project-name/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/user/Desktop/coding/project-name/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 505

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not load module metadata from /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.63/descriptors/com.android.support/transition/28.0.0/6740fe48b44caed96d7f50b66ff7b0b5/descriptor.bin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check your `project-name` and can you make sure that applicaion id is same in package.json and app.gradle inside App_resorces folder?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it using Android Stuio.

1. I went to `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart`
2. I shut down Android Studio
3. Removed the `.gradle` folder, which in Ubuntu is located in the home directory

Then, I was successfully able to build my NativeScript project.